# Cannot access {variable-name} before initialization (React import)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, referenceerror

I'm getting a Reference Error

> Cannot access 'STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID' before initialization

I have a structureColumn file which contains the following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Column from './column';

export const STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID = 'Structure';

export default class StructureColumn extends Column {
  constructor(name) {
    super(STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID);
  }

  clone() {
    return new StructureColumn(this.name);
  }

  getKey() {
    return STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID;
  }
}
```

When trying to access `StructureColumn` class or `STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID` variable from a component I get the mentioned error.

The component looks the following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { List, ListItem, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import { STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID } from '../../../../models/structureColumn';

console.log(STRUCTURE_COLUMN_ID);

const CustomColumnsList = ({ onSelect }) => {
  return (
    <List>
      {Object.values({}).map(col => (
        <Tooltip title={col.description}>
          <ListItem onClick={() => onSelect(col.column)} button>
            {col.name}
          </ListItem>
        </Tooltip>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

export default CustomColumnsList;
```

I can use the variable inside the functional component body but the thing is I wanted to create a constant variable out of it's scope. Never seen this issue before in React. Someone has an experience dealing with it?

Comment: This can only happen with a circular dependency. If you need to use those, never reference your variables outside of functions. Remove the `console.log`, or move it into the module that declares the constant, and it will work.

Comment: @Bergi Turns out there was a circular dependency although it was rather hidden. Basically what happened I had a variable in constants.js file which was used in another file and when trying to import StructureColumn it somehow started to show this error even though the circular dependency was there from the start. I don't why this happened but I will not bother and refactor the constants.js file. Thank you for your help! I can't vote unfortunately. P.S.: people, don't just put constants in one file :)

Comment: If you have a circular dependency, which of the modules in the cycle is evaluated first depends on the order of `import` statements in the whole project. This means the errors can surface on changes in unrelated files.